# Horizontally align CSS arrow and text

Tags: html, css

I've got some text and a CSS arrow inside a button, but I can't horizontally align them - the arrow is below the text:

[image]

I've tried adding `vertical-align: middle;` to `.down-arrow` but it doesn't horizontally align them. I've also tried adding `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the button but to no avail.

```css
.down-arrow {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<button>Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1L3odx6s/

Comment: try     vertical-align: 2px; on the arrow for example

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that seems to work. I'm guessing it has to be done 'manually' by entering the specific px amount like that, rather than automatically using something like align-items: center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the transformation differently and you can use `vertical-align:middle`

```css
.down-arrow {
  transform: translateY(25%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

```html
<button>Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>

<button style="font-size:30px">Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
<button style="font-size:50px">Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
<button style="font-size:50px">Text<span class="down-arrow" style="padding:5px;border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;"></span></button>
<button style="font-size:50px">Text<span class="down-arrow" style="padding:8px"></span></button>
```

Or a custom value for `vertical-align`

```css
.down-arrow {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  vertical-align: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<button>Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>

<button style="font-size:30px">Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
<button style="font-size:50px">Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
<button style="font-size:50px">Text<span class="down-arrow" style="padding:5px;border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;"></span></button>
<button style="font-size:50px">Text<span class="down-arrow" style="padding:8px"></span></button>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution thanks, I'm not too experienced with transformations though so think I'll stick with your original answer in the comment

Comment: @TheCodesee check the update then, used the same idea as my comment with a more generice value so it works in all the cases

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this easily.

One way to do this use `vertical-align`

**Using vertical-align**

```css
.down-arrow {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  vertical-align: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button>Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
```

**Flex technique**

The other way is use `flex` on your button and use `margin-top: 3px`

Using `flex` and `margin-top`

You can read more about using flex boxes and easy recemended techniques [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.down-arrow {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

button {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button>Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
```

**Using align-items**

```css
.down-arrow {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button>Text<span class="down-arrow"></span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, think I'll go with the `vertical-align: 2px` solution. I already tried the `align-items` solution but this didn't work

Comment: @TheCodesee Glad that you found it helpful. There are multiple ways - I would recommend using `flex` techniques as well. But its upto you. I have added a link where you learn more about using `flex` box techinique. Cheers